# Tensorflow tf.squeeze alternatives

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I have the following image:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly()    

img = Image.open('image.jpg')
try:
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype='uint8' )
except SystemError:
    data = np.asarray(img.getdata(), dtype='uint8' )
```

Reshaping:

```
tf.shape(data)
<tf.Tensor: id=2, shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([263, 320,   3], dtype=int32)>

image = tf.expand_dims(data, 0)
tf.shape(image)
<tf.Tensor: id=16, shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([  1, 263, 320,   3], dtype=int32)>

 tf.squeeze(image, squeeze_dims=[0])
<tf.Tensor: id=22, shape=(263, 320, 3), dtype=uint8, numpy=...>
```

How to replace the last `tf.squeeze` with similar command (Example: `tf.reshape`)?

Comment: `tf.reshape(image, [263, 320, 3], name=None)`

Comment: How could I make this generic? Without specifically selecting the 3 elements of the Tensor?

Comment: @spicyramen do you mean like it need not necessarily be 4 dimensions?

Comment: I will always process images, and need to tf.expand_dims(data, 0) first which convert the tensor into 4 dimensions, and then squeeze, just looking for an squeeze alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative, if you know the size of the first dimension is 1, you can do:

```
tf.reshape(image, tf.shape(image)[1:])
```

As has been stated, though, `tf.squeeze` seems to be the straightforward solution in your case.

Comment: Just wondering, do you know how "smart" reshape is in this case? Intuitively it seems a bit wasteful to reshape here instead of just indexing, but I guess that maybe reshape sees that the shape is "almost" matching up already and simply drops the first dimension.

Comment: @xdurch0 I don't really know, I mean at least for contiguous tensors reshape should just be a change in the shape information and no further computation, but in any case it takes more steps, namely querying the initial shape and slicing it (even if it is negligible computational effort). Personally I'd do it with squeeze or with indexing, like in your answer (I posted the reshape solution because the question suggested it), mostly for clarity, but yeah maybe in some cases it may be also more performant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `image[0]` to select the first "row" of the image. If `image` is shape `[1, w, h, c]` this will return a `[w, h, c]` tensor. Although I don't understand what the issue with `tf.squeeze` is. `squeeze(image, axis=0)` does the same thing and protects against cases where other axes (e.g. the channel axis) are also size 1.